# Schedulable Batch Apex - Create Tasks

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, tasks

I'm looking to run a scheduled apex batch class that will create a task on any Contact record that had a sales rep assigned to them 1 day ago that hasn't been emailed yet.

I've created 2 custom fields to filter the criteria above.. the date the Contact was assigned a sales rep `Sales_Rep_Updated__c` and a checkbox field that will be checked as soon as an Email task is completed, `Welcome_Email_Sent__c`

**Here is my Schedulable Batch Class**

```
global class Followup24Email Implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<sObject>{
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    Database.executeBatch(this);
}

//This is the query that is passed to the execute method.  It queries all of the Contacts who have passed
String query = 'Select Id, AccountId, OwnerId, Sales_Rep_Updated__c FROM Contact WHERE Sales_Rep_Updated__c = YESTERDAY AND Welcome_Email_Sent__c = FALSE';

global database.queryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return database.getQueryLocator(query);

} //close start method

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, list <Contact> scope) {

    List <Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

    // Iterate through the whole query of Contacts
    // Create a Task that's associated with each Contact.
    for(Contact c : scope) {
            Task tsk             = new Task();
            tsk.OwnerId          = c.OwnerId;
            tsk.WhoId            = c.Id;
            tsk.WhatId           = c.AccountId;
            tsk.ActivityDate     = System.today();
            tsk.Status           = 'Open';
            tsk.Priority         = 'Normal';
            tsk.Subject          = 'Send Welcome Email';
            tsk.Description      = 'This Account was recently assigned to you, please send them a welcome email.';
            tsk.Type             = 'Email';
            tsk.IsReminderSet    = true;
            tsk.ReminderDateTime = System.now();

            taskList.add(tsk);
    } //close for-loop

    try {
        insert taskList;
    } catch (system.dmlexception e) {
        System.debug('Tasks not inserted: ' + e);
    }
} //close execute method

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {


} //close finish method
}
```

**And here is my Test class - currently getting 92% (24/26) code coverage**

```
@isTest
private class Followup24EmailTest {

static testMethod void TestFollowup24Email() {

// User Id's for the two sales managers.
String aId = '00561000001DTdh';

List <Contact> contacts = new List <Contact>();
List <Task> tasks = new List <Task>();

// Create 50 Contacts

for (integer i=0; i<50; i++) {
Contact c = new Contact(FirstName='Test',
            LastName='Contact'+ i,
            Sales_Rep_Updated__c = Date.today().addDays(-1),
            Welcome_Email_Sent__c = false,
            OwnerId = aId);
contacts.add(c);

} //close for-loop

insert contacts;

Test.StartTest();

// Call the Batch Apex method.
Followup24Email fue = new Followup24Email();
ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(fue);

Test.StopTest();

List<Task> taskResult = [SELECT ID From TASK];
System.debug('taskResult' + taskResult.size());
/*AsyncApexJob async = [Select Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,     TotalJobItems from AsyncApexJob where Id = :batchprocessid];
System.debug('Final results are ' + async);

System.AssertEquals(async.NumberOfErrors, 0);
System.AssertEquals([Select count() from Contact Where OwnerId=:aId AND    FirstName='Test'], 50);
System.AssertEquals([Select count() from Task Where Subject = 'Send Welcome    Email'], 50);*/

} //close testmethod

} //close Class
```

I've created a few test Accounts / Contacts with criteria that should fit (Welcome Email Sent = unchecked, and a Sales Rep Update date of yesterday) but no tasks are ever created.

---

### Edit:

Here is what's not getting covered in my test
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You're scheduling this through apex?

Comment: I'd like to do it through the UI if possible, maybe that's where I've gone wrong?

Comment: No that's fine.. Why are you building Tasks in your test data?

Comment: are you sure that Welcome_Email_Sent__c  == false?   also doing system.debug during an exception just swallows the error.. not best behaviour

Comment: @EricSSH good call, lol I'm a bit brain dead today.. I'll remove that part and just insert the contacts.

Comment: @BenjaminPirih Yea, when `Welcome_Email_Sent__c` == True / checked, that means a welcome email was already sent to that customer, so I don't want to open another task for that contact

Comment: also why are you calling: update scope; at the end of your batch transaction?  Don't see any reason why you would want to do this..

Comment: As an aside, this is why you need proper asserts. You test is failing but it is not working as expected. Proper asserts would help identify that it was not working. As for what is not working, run the test, review the test code coverage and see what is not covered. It will give you an idea of what is going wrong. Your test should NOT be passing if you cannot get it working int he UI

Comment: another aside - global modifier is not required; use public unless you are building a managed package

Comment: Thanks for the help / tips guys, I'm still fairly new to SF and apex, so a lot of this is over my head.  I've updated with 2 lines that are not being covered in test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this for your tests and work from there

```
@isTest
private class Followup24EmailTest {

static testMethod void TestFollowup24Email() {

// User Id's for the two sales managers.
String aId = '00561000001DTdh';

List <Contact> contacts = new List <Contact>();
List <Task> tasks = new List <Task>();

// Create 50 Contacts and assign them to the sales manager of the opposite location.

for (integer i=0; i<50; i++) {
    Contact c = new Contact(FirstName='Test',
                LastName='Contact'+ i,
                Sales_Rep_Updated__c = Date.today().addDays(-1),
                Welcome_Email_Sent__c  = false,
                OwnerId = aId);
    contacts.add(c);

} //close for-loop

insert contacts;

Test.StartTest();

// Call the Batch Apex method.
Followup24Email fue = new Followup24Email();
ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(fue);

Test.StopTest();

List<Task> taskResult = [SELECT ID From TASK];
System.debug('taskResult' + taskResults.size());
/*AsyncApexJob async = [Select Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems from AsyncApexJob where Id = :batchprocessid];
System.debug('Final results are ' + async);

System.AssertEquals(async.NumberOfErrors, 0);
System.AssertEquals([Select count() from Contact Where OwnerId=:aId AND FirstName='Test'], 50);
System.AssertEquals([Select count() from Task Where Subject = 'Send Welcome Email'], 50);*/

} //close testmethod

} //close Class
```

Comment: perhaps mocking the user would be best practice here; as well as asserting the # of tasks

Comment: Right, he should be asserting the tasks, but asserting before you actually know if the tasks are created are a pain since there is usually an issue of seeing the debug logs if the assert fails, but what would mocking do in this case?  This wasn't meant to be a solid answer, but more of a starting point to get his tests moving in the right direction

Comment: sorry - OP has a hardcoded ID set for `aId`; easy to miss

Comment: @EricSSH Thanks for the help, I was able to find the issue, it wasn't with this class at all, there was an error in a completely separate class. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

global class CreateTaskForContact implements Database.Batchable  {

```
string query = 'Select Id , AccountId , OwnerId from Contact Where Welcome_Email_Sent__c= False';

global database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext Bc){
    return  database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> conList){
    
    List<Task>tskList = new List<Task>();
    
    for (Contact con: conList){
        
        Task tsk = new Task();
        tsk.OwnerId= con.ownerId;
        tsk.whoId= con.Id;
        tsk.WhatId=con.AccountId;
        tsk.Subject='Send Welcome Email';
        tsk.Status= 'open';
        tsk.Priority= 'Normal';
        tsk.Description= 'This is test Batch Apex for Contact to create a task if checkbox fieeld is unchecked';
        tsk.ActivityDate= System.Today();
        tsk.IsReminderSet= true;
        tsk.ReminderDateTime= System.now();
        tskList.add(tsk);
    }
    try {
        insert tskList;
    }
    catch(system.DmlException error){
        System.debug('Task not Inserted!!'+error);
    }
}
global void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC){
    
}
```

}

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.